# Converting Datatable to PagedList to show in razor pages C#

Tags: c#, pagedlist

I have a datatable to show in my View.But I need to show it as a paged list in view.What is the easiest solution for that.

My controller:

```
 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("AllStory", sqlConnection);
                sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
            if(dataTable.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                var newTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date")).CopyToDataTable();
                return View(newTable);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(dataTable);
            }
```

My View :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
{
            
                <div class="row">@Model.Rows[i]["Title"]</div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Model.Rows[i]["Author"] @Model.Rows[i]["date"]
                
            
            <div>
                <div>@Model.Rows[i]["Body"]</div>
            </div>
        </div

        </div>
  }
```

Comment: is your code working or not?

Comment: easiest way, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-paging-functionality-to-the-index-method

Comment: I just show some important part of working part of my code. But the main thing I want to know how to implement paging from the datatble ,if you can see it in the controller.

Comment: @SandipBantawa,But I have a datatable ,how can I convert it to paged list.